# Convert netCDF file into dataframe with python3

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, netcdf, data-conversion

I have a netcdf file with the dimensions time=1, lat=901 and lon=3600 (Look at the screen for more info about the file) containing the variable "sde" that I'm going to convert into dataframe with columns: time, lat, lon and the variable "sde", I tried several methods on the net, but they don't work.
Any suggestion will be appreciated!
Cheers
Hamid 
Here are some of methods I was testing:

1. First method:
   `f = xr.open_dataset('/media/hamid/Elements/SD_mean_2018-12-01.nc4')                                    df=f.to_dataframe().unstack()`
2. Second method:
   `f = nc.Dataset('/media/hamid/Elements/SD_mean_2018-12-01.nc4', mode='r')                               ds = xr.open_dataset(xr.backends.NetCDF4DataStore(f))                  df=ds.to_dataframe()`                                                                                 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Khlxq.png)

Comment: Your code should work. Please explain why it is not working

Comment: The program return a dataframe with just tow variable "time_bonds" and "sde" and the number of lines is doubled, normally I should get 3 243 600 rows, but I got the double 6 487 200.                                                                                                                           Normally, i should get df of 3 243 600 rows and the variables time, lat, lon and sde       Thank you Robert Wilson